# create mobile uploads album

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photos

I can't find documentation on how to create the Mobile Uploads photo album using the Graph API.  (the one that allows you to do post-by-email) Is this possible?  If so how, and what permissions do I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. And the issue you're facing is a FB BUG: developers.facebook.com/bugs/445723968802294

Report it!